# Erase multiple packages using rpm or yum

Tags: unix, rpm, yum

I was given access to a server with 50+ php rpms installed. I'm trying to remove them all.

Basically, I'm trying to combine these two commands:

```
rpm -qa | grep 'php'
```

and

```
rpm --erase
```

I know a little about pipes and redirection, but I don't see how to use them for this purpose. Please help.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

### Using `yum`

List and remove the indicated packages and all their dependencies, but with a `y/N` confirmation:

```
yum remove 'php*'
```

To bypass the confirmation, replace `yum` with `yum -y`.

### Using `rpm`

This section builds upon the answers by [twalburg](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12009218/832230) and [Ricardo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16769089/832230).

List which RPMs are installed:

```
rpm -qa 'php*'
rpm -qa | grep '^php'  # Alternative listing.
```

List which RPMs which will be erased, without actually erasing them:

```
rpm -e --test -vv $(rpm -qa 'php*') 2>&1 | grep '^D:     erase:'
```

On Amazon Linux, you may need to use `grep '^D: ========== ---'` instead.

If the relevant RPMs are not listed by the command above, investigate errors:

```
rpm -e --test -vv $(rpm -qa 'php*')
```

Erase these RPMs:

```
rpm -e $(rpm -qa 'php*')
```

Confirm the erasure:

```
rpm -qa 'php*'
```

Comment: The `grep` command doesn't pick up anything on my Amazon Linux instance, I think it should be looking for `'^D: ========== ---'` instead. Also (because this is non-obvious), in the case of multiple wildcards (e.g., LibreOffice), the query command would look like `rpm -qa 'libreoffice*' 'libobasis*'`.

Answer (score 10):

The usual tool for this job is [`xargs`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/xargs):

```
rpm -qa | grep 'php' | xargs rpm -e
```

This will call `rpm -e` with all packages named in the standard input of `xargs` as arguments.

Comment: This approach will often simply fail due to dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use the output of `rpm -qa | grep ...` in the `rpm --erase` command directly:

```
rpm --erase `rpm -qa | grep php`
```

Maybe not for the `php` case you're citing, but the `xargs` approach might possibly run into issues if it decides to split the list into several invocations of `rpm -e` and the first list contains packages that are dependencies of packages in subsequent lists. Of course, if you're removing that many packages all at once, you might have other things that you need to consider...

Answer (score 0):

to list:

```
rpm -qa | grep 'php'
```

to remove instaled listed and filtrated:

```
rpm -e $(rpm -qa |grep 'php')
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this today. Using --justdb and --noscripts rpm parameters wasn't sufficient without the --allmatches, and that's it.

```
[root@localhost ~]# rpm -ev --allmatches --justdb <the-package-name>
```

https://mcvictech.blogspot.com/2011/10/rpm-error-specifies-multiple-packages.html