# how to remove packages from yum list result?

Tags: yum

probably a quick question for experts. on linux(Centso)

I did something like

```
$ yum list | grep cdh
```

which returns a bunch of items(I was search to remove cloudera packages)

I know that I can remove them by

```
$ yum remove ...
```

but certainly like to do it in one command. Is there a way to do so? many thanks

currently. I manually output the list result to a text file, and then copy/paste the names into yum remove. there must be a better way. thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [rpm - erase multiple packages](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12005526/rpm-erase-multiple-packages)

Answer (score 1):

`yum remove '*cdh*'` will do what you want. Though be careful to check the list of packages it wants to remove to make sure the pattern didn't catch too much.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove in bulk by using a wildcard.

```
yum remove 'cdh*'
```

There is more information here [rpm - erase multiple packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12005526/rpm-erase-multiple-packages)

Comment: thanks. the rpm link helps a lot. and the wildcard works too.